# Need to restart mysql server, but I don't have root access: what are my options?

Tags: centos-7

The server admin is ill and unreacheable, I have virtual server accounts. The mysql server crashed, and have no backup. The system is a centos 7 with virtualmin.

Comment: Without the ability to login into the server and gracefully shutdown the machine, you only have one other choice, and that is to do it by force.  Press and hold the power button.  You should avoid doing this unless you are authorized to do so and understand the risk to the database.

Comment: The server admin should have planted all system & application passwords in an envelope for example to ensure that this kind of issue does not require such force. What if they just ups and leaves? What if they die? First thing you should do is when they come back - get a written backup of the passwords salted away somewhere else you could he held hostage.

Comment: Ohh, I forgot to tell you, I can log in with several accouts, but no root o sudoer. @Bib: totally agree.

Comment: This is known as the [Bus Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor). You have a bus factor of 1. That is bad, very bad.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand the bus factor (or lottery factor, if you're one of those flippin' "sunny disposition" people) is the number you can lose WITHOUT operations failing, meaning this orgs m80-went-off-in-the-lads-pocket number would be zero. Though, I may be wrong. Just how I recall hearing it.

Comment: @music2myear - ah, yes, zero-based. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done, and it would be a poor system if it could be.

Remember, any system that you can get from access to one Db all the way to now I can restart the server would be compromised by bad actors in moments. The same good choices keeping them out are also keeping you out.